# Do I need to encapsulate awk variables in quotes in order to sanitize them?

Tags: shell, shell-script, security, awk, quoting

As per an [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273074/sanitize-user-input-in-bash-for-security-purposes/4273137#4273137), it's my understanding that encapsulating bash variables in double-quotes is a fairly safe way of sanitizing user input.

What about awk variables?  For example, if I have something like:

```
awk -v SOURCEIP="$SOURCEIP" -v REVERSEDNS="$REVERSEDNS" '{
   gsub(/^_TMPSOURCEIP_/, SOURCEIP);
   gsub(/^_TMPREVERSEDNS_/, REVERSEDNS);
   print
}' /home/foo/footemplate
```

Should I put quotes around the variable in the gsub lines? So it would then look like:

```
awk -v SOURCEIP="$SOURCEIP" -v REVERSEDNS="$REVERSEDNS" '{
   gsub(/^_TMPSOURCEIP_/, "SOURCEIP");
   gsub(/^_TMPREVERSEDNS_/, "REVERSEDNS");
   print
}' /home/foo/footemplate
```

Or does this not make a difference?

Comment: Nope, if you'll take SOURCEIP in quotes inside awk, it won't be processed as variable.

Answer (score 5):

(OK, sorry I read your question too quickly, so some of my answer is a bit beside the point, still leaving it as it is as it may be useful to you or some)

There are several things to consider here.

### quoting of *shell* variables

Leaving a variable unquoted in POSIX shells (in list contexts, like in arguments to a command), not `awk`, is the split+glob operator.

If you do:

```
cmd foo=$var
```

Where `$var` is `* *`.

Tha't asking the shell to split the content of `$var` based on the value of the `$IFS` special shell variable, by default on blanks. So above, that gives us `foo=*` and `*` and perform globbing on each of those, that is expand `foo=*` to all the filenames in the current directory that start with `foo=` and `*` to all the non-hidden filenames.

So, really, you should almost always quote your *shell* variables, whether they are arguments to `awk` or not. That also applies to shell command substitution (`` `...` `` and `$(...)`) and shell arithmetic expansion (`$((...))`).

### passing data as-is to `awk`

The other problem is that `awk` (not the shell) expands backslash escape sequences in the assignments of variables like `-v var=value`  (and with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [if the value starts with `@/` and ends in `/`, it's treated as a regexp type of variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)).

For instance, `-v var='\n/\n/'` sets the content of the `awk` `var` variable to `<newline>/<newline>/`, not `\n/\n/`. That also applies to `awk` variables defined as:

```
awk '...' var=value
```

To pass data to `awk` without it undergoing that expansion, you can use the `ENVIRON` or `ARGV` awk arrays:

```
var=$value awk 'BEGIN {var=ENVIRON["var"]} ...'
```

(above, it's a shell variable assignment (to a non-array variable), so there can't be split+glob, which is one of the rare cases where you can omit the quotes around variables)

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN {var=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]} ...' "$value"
```

### quoting and `awk` variables

That split+glob is only a shell (mis-)feature. The `awk` language is a completely different language.

In `awk`, variables are refered to a `varname`, not `$varname` and quotes are used to introduce strings. So `"varname"` is the `varname` string, while `varname` refers to the variable.

### sanitizing variables to avoid code injection

Strictly speaking, quoting shell variables is not sanitizing, it's *not quoting the variables* that is using the split+glob operator. While in most languages you put quotes around fixed strings, in shells, it's the other way round: every thing is string and quotes are used to prevent some special behaviour, and especially variables should almost always be quoted (a poor design decision that kind of made sense in the Bourne shell in the 70s, but is a hindrance in modern shells, `zsh` being the only shell that partly fixed that).

The shell or awk will not evaluate/interpret code stored in their own variable unless you tell them to.

```
var='foo; rm -f var'
echo $var
# or
echo "$var"
```

Will not cause the content of the variable to be evaluated as shell code (though the first one will undergo splitting and globbing which can have dire consequences (for instance with `var='/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*'`). You'd need:

```
eval "echo $var"
# or
sh -c "echo $var"
```

for it to be evaluated/interpreted as shell code.

`awk` doesn't have such an `eval` feature. `perl`/`python` do.

But beware of cross-contamination. You can have the shell pass variable data (in *shell* variables) as code to execute by `awk`:

```
awk '{print "'"$var"': " $0}'
```

would be dangerous in case the `$var` *shell* variable contains for instance:

```
var='test"; print "foo" > /etc/passwd; print "blah'
```

because the shell would then execute:

```
["awk", "{print \"test\"; print \"foo\" > /etc/passwd; print \"blah: \" $0}"]
```

Or the other way round:

```
awk '{system("echo foo: " $0)}' < file
```

where `awk` would run a shell as:

```
["sh", "-c", "echo foo: content-of-the-line"]
```

for each line of `file` (and think of what a line like `; rm -rf /` would do).

It's not only  between `awk` and `sh`. You've got to be careful whenever variable/uncontrolled data may be evaluated as code  by another interpreter. Examples are:

```
sed "s/$regexp/blah/g"
```

`sed`'s language is limited but it can still to harm, like with `regexp='//;w /etc/passwd; s/`'.

Or:

```
find . -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;
```

Now, to avoid those problems, there are two general approaches:

1. convert the *variable* from one interpreter to the other. That works for the shell -> awk or find -> sh case above. Like change:

   ```
   awk '{print "'"$var"': " $0}'
   ```

   to:

   ```
   awk -v awk_var="$var" '{print awk_var ": " $0}'
   ```

   And:

   ```
   find . -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;
   ```

   to:

   ```
   find . -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"' sh {} \;
   ```

   but that won't work for the shell -> sed, or awk -> shell cases.
2. when 1 is not possible, you need to sanitize the variables to either remove or escape the characters that may be a problem. In,

   ```
   awk '{system("echo foo: " $0)}'
   ```

   you need to convert `$0` to something that is a clean string as far as the shell is concerned. One option is to prefix each character with a backslash but that won't work for newline (not a problem here). Another one is to enclose the string in single quotes and escape each single quote.

   ```
   awk 'function escape(s) {
          gsub(/'\''/,"&\\\\&&",s)
          return "'\''" s "'\''"
        }
        {system("echo foo: " escape($0))}'
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that's great information.  I'm still a little confused on the "safety" of passing stuff around like that.  In my case, I DO want it to expand but I don't want it to wreak havoc. For the purpose of discussion, let's say that the value of the shell variable `$SOURCEIP` is `rm -fr /`.  If I pass that to awk via `awk -v AWKVAREXAMPLE="$SOURCEIP"` and then later have awk do a gsub like `gsub(/^_TARGETSTRING_/, AWKVAREXAMPLE);` would that eventually "leak" out into the shell and destroy everything?

Comment: @MikeB, no. It would leak out to the shell if `awk` invoked a shell and passed that as a code for it to interpret like in: `awk '{system("echo " var)}'` (where `var` is `;rm -rf /`), where `awk` calls `["sh", "-c", "echo; rm -rf /"]` or `awk '{print | "tr " v1 " " v2}'` where `awk` pipes the output to `["sh", "-c", "tr content-of-v1 content-of-v2"]`.

Comment: Things that you want to avoid are like: `awk "{print \"$shell_variables\"}"` as there,  the content of the shell variable is interpreted as awk code.

Answer (score 5):

These two examples demonstrate the difference:

```
$ echo _TMP_ | awk -v VAR='some "text"' '{ gsub(/_TMP_/, VAR) ; print }'
some "text"
$ echo _TMP_ | awk -v VAR='some "text"' '{ gsub(/_TMP_/, "VAR") ; print }'
VAR
```

When `VAR` is unquoted, `awk` treats it as a variable with the value `some "text"`.  When `VAR` is inside quotes, awk treats it as a three-character string.

**MORE:**  `bash` has sanitizing issues.  Consider:

```
$ VAR="rm important_file" ; $VAR
```

The above will erase `important_file`.  In this way,  `bash` is like a macro language: it will substitute for a variable and then try to execute the result. `awk` is different. Consider:

```
$ echo _TMP_ | awk -v VAR='var); print $1' '{ gsub(/_TMP_/, VAR) ; print }'
var); print $1
```

`awk` treats `VAR` like mere text, not like potential commands to execute.

Problems can arise, however, if one lets `bash` modify the `awk` script.  In my examples above, the `awk` scripts were all in single-quotes.  That prevents `bash` from messing with them.

Comment: `VAR='blah; echo $1'` is not a problem to the shell either (unless you use `eval`). It's not a macro language (except to some extent wrt alias expansion)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing an Awk variable to *system*, you need to shell quote it:

```
function quote(str,   d, m, x, y, z) {
  d = "\47"; m = split(str, x, d)
  for (y in x) z = z d x[y] d (y < m ? "\\" d : "")
  return z
}
```

Example:

```
system(sprintf("ffmpeg -i %s outfile.m4a", quote(ARGV[1])))
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/3216068/stdlib.awk#L26-L32)