# Make grep work for special filenames

Tags: bash, shell, grep, filenames

I have a set of `txt` files whose names may contain space or special characters like `#`.

I have a `grep` solution `grep -L "cannot have" $(grep -l "must have" *.txt)` to list all the files who have `must have` but not `cannot have`.

For instance, there is a file `abc defg.txt` which contains only 1 line: `must have`.

So normally the grep solution should find out `abc defg.txt`, but it returns:

```
grep: abc: No such file or directory
grep: defg.txt: No such file or directory
```

I think for filenames containing `#`, the grep solution is also invalid.

Could anyone help me amend the grep solution?

Comment: `#` would not be a problem (except with `zsh -o globsubst -o extendedglob`), but `*`, `?`, `[`, space, tab, newline would be with `bash`.

Comment: `find . -type f -name \*.txt -exec grep -qF 'must have' {} \; ! -exec grep -qF 'cannot have' {} \; -print`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using GNU specific options (`-L`), you could do:

```
grep -lZ -- "must have" *.txt | xargs -r0 grep -L -- "cannot have"
```

The idea being to use `-Z` to print the list of file names NUL-delimited and use `xargs -r0` to pass that list as arguments to the second `grep`.

Command substitution, by default, splits on space, tab and newline (and NUL in `zsh`). Bourne-like shells other than `zsh` also perform globbing upon each word resulting of that splitting.

You could do:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only
set -f # disable globbing
grep -L -- "cannot have" $(
    set +f # we need globbing for *.txt in this subshell though
    grep -l -- "must have" *.txt
  )
```

But that would still break on filenames containing newline characters.

In `zsh` (and `zsh` only), you can do:

```
IFS=$'\0'
grep -L -- "cannot have" $(grep -lZ -- "must have" *.txt)
```

Or:

```
grep -L -- "cannot have" ${(ps:\0:)"$(grep -lZ -- "must have" *.txt)"}
```

Comment: What's the point in specifying `*.txt` as the argument after disabling globbing?

Comment: @devnull, good point. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

**IF** you're willing to go further afield, awk can do it in one pass:

```
awk 'function s(){if(a&&!b){print f}} FNR==1{s();f=FILENAME;a=b=0} 
  /must have/{a=1} /cannot have/{b=1} END{s()}' filepattern
```

For recentish gawk you can simplify with BEGINFILE and ENDFILE.
(Like all awk answers you can put the awk commands in a file with -f, 
and like most you can easily convert to perl if you prefer.)

Comment: Note however that `grep -l/L` stops reading at the first match so is likely  to be more efficient (also because of the general `awk` code interpretation overhead). With GNU `awk`, you could use `nextfile` to avoid reading the whole file when it can be avoided (when `cannot have` is found).

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `find` instead and `grep` using a shell command:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'grep -q "must have" -- "{}" && grep -L "cannot have" -- "{}"'
```

Comment: never embed `{}` in the shell code!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I trust that is a meaningful rule, but could you give a hint to find an explanation?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, that's a classic code injection vulnerability, it's on the level of passing unsanitized data to `eval`, as here, you're passing arbitrary file names as **code** to `sh` (think of a `$(reboot).txt` lurking in the directory for instance). You'll find it discussed in many Q&As here. See for instance [Do I need to encapsulate awk variables in quotes in order to sanitize them?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113799)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, makes sense - I was just thinking about something directl related to `xargs`, because `xargs` option `-i` without argument defaults to `-I{}` ( the `{}` will not be part of the shell code)